# How to insert arabic characters into sql server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have deployed an application, and suddenly the users needed the ability to store arabic characters into the database.
The problem is that I used the entity framework so I have no access to SQL queries to add the 'N' character.
Is there any other solution at database level to do that??
Or how is it possible to do that at the Entity Framework level?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to change anything but how the SQL stores information. If you can change the default store to utf-8 instead of Latin, which is probably your default you will not have to do anything.

See this post: http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/changing-mysql-default-character-sets-to-utf-8

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i'll try that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to change anything** in your code or in **EF** level.

They are compatible with Arabic letters.

You should change **collation** of your **DB**.

I generally use: **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS** as collation for my database. With this collation you can store any query Arabic letters perfectly.

Comment: thank you for your response, i'll try that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried this, still the problem not solve, as Entity Framework not taking it automatically, in the end we got the Arabic letters change into '?' question marks.

So the best way to do it which I've chosen is to change the way of insertion, use IN-LINE query for that particular code, it sounds pathetic, but still sometimes we have to full fill the required which is most important.

Finally, the records are saved in Arabic and fetched in the customized rich textbox in the same way which is it supposed to be.

If anyone found better way, please feel free to reply to my solution.

Cheers,
- Meesam.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement this by simple updating varchar to nvarchar. And updated the entity class accordingly. Nothing i changed in collation. it works like a charm.